# How to make a Post Tag primary?

Tags: tags, javascript

We are trying to rethink how a blog is laid out, by using Tags as primary headers for each post, instead of Categories.

In order to do this, we have to set a Tag for the post as Primary.

So, we are trying to read the Tags as they are input into the Post Tags widget in the Post Admin, by using Javascript to read the AJAX output printed to the page. We have accomplished that part of the equation.

What we haven't be able to do, is then use document.write after printing the tags using .ready  to another widget we created, so that the end user may select one of the Tags as primary.

For some reason, it does not seem to like the document.write statement and we're not sure why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to get the tags BEFORE the user publishes the post. The tags don't exist in meta until publish, so we're trying to grab them from the AJAX display, so we can select one of them as primary, and have that become the "tag category" of the post.

Comment: What do you mean by "set a Tag for the post as Primary"? What does that mean? Have you considered using **hierarchical categories**, or else using a **custom taxonomy** for your purposes? As-described, this sounds like trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Hey Chip, sorry...I'm not the most experienced user here, so I'll look at how to accept the answers. I thought voting was accepting. I'll have to check each post to see how to accept. I'm assuming it's the checkmark that you click on, is that right?

Comment: I haven't tried using hierarchical categories or a custom taxonomy. The goal of the newsroom editor was to have the journalist not use Categories, because then we'd have a giant list of categories to scroll, instead of inputting a tag and getting a suggested tag that was already in the DB, or creating a new tag, without creating a new category. Custom taxonomy I am not familiar with, so I will look into that. But, the goal was to have the user input a set of tags, then select one of the tags as primary for that post. We're experimenting, so it's not supposed to make sense, if you will.

Comment: I just looked here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies to understand Custom Taxonomies. So what you're saying is that i can create a custom taxonomy, get a post meta box, and that post meta box (according to the wiki) is created just like a Tags. The only problem I see with that is that we would duplicate a Tag and a Custom Taxonomy entry...which also doesn't make sense. We want to make the one tag already entered primary. So, we want to somehow make a tag in the Tag meta box clickable to be a primary tag, or take the list of tags in a new meta box and choose which one is primary.

Comment: I'm saying **replace** the concept of **Primary Tag** with **Custom Taxonomy** (that you could even call *Primary Tag*). That way, you can tag the post however you want, and then designate the "Primary Tag", via the custom taxonomy. Whatever you list in the custom taxonomy, you *don't list* as a Post Tag.

Comment: One more thing...for usability, you don't want the user to have to retype the tag in a new post meta box. That's redundant. That's why we need the user to select a tag in Tags as primary, then use that tag to catgorize

Comment: I'm going to compose my suggestion, and then move it into an answer, for further discussion.

Comment: This also has to be flexible. The reason we want to use Tags is that they can be anything. So, what you're saying is to use a custom taxonomy, but even still, if the author is typing in the custom taxonomy, it still adds them in alpha order and we couldn't select the first entry as primary, because the meta isn't posted to the database until AFTER you publish the post. The way it comes into the tags meta box is via AJAX and that's just printed to the post meta box BEFORE publish. So, you can't pull that primary tag via php until after its published, right? Okay...thanks for posting an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1650/discussion-between-tony-zeoli-and-chip-bennett)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone on on of my listserves provided the answer:

He said to, "use innerHTML() within your ajax callback function.  It looks like you're using jquery, so use the .load() function."

I checked on the jquery site and it said .innerHTML is .html in jQuery, so we'll go with that then and see if we can pull the AJAX data and print it somewhere else using that function.